# How can I write a type for an array with other arrays nested inside it?

Tags: typescript

I have the following structure:

```
[
    [
        [0,0,0],
        [1,1,1],
        [0,0,0],
    ],
        [
        [0,1,0],
        [0,1,0],
        [0,1,0],
    ]
]
```

How can I avoid this ugly notation? Perhaps by writing types...

```
allPatterns: number[][][] = [];
```

Comment: What "ugly notation" are you talking about?  Are you missing an opening bracket?  What, specifically, doesn't work for you about `number[][][]`?

Comment: @jcalz,
I'm wondering if there is a way to shorten this entry. So that for example, with one more nesting, there would be no such: ```number[][][][]```

Comment: There's nothing built in... someone could write a `NestedArray` utility type where `NestedArray<number, 3>` evaluates to `number[][][]`, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAdPQN) shows, but it's not obvious to me that it's an improvement to do this.  Is that what you want to see?  If so I could write up an answer explaining how it works (but you should [edit] the question to explicitly and clearly state what the question is; replace "this ugly notation" with "manually writing out a series of brackets").  If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, you could label the inner types:

```
// Any set of three numbers
type MatrixRow = [number, number, number];
// Any set of three rows
type Matrix = [MatrixRow, MatrixRow, MatrixRow];

const exampleA: Matrix[] = [
    [
        [0,0,0],
        [1,1,1],
        [0,0,0],
    ], [
        [0,1,0],
        [0,1,0],
        [0,1,0],
    ]
];

const exampleB: Matrix[] = [];
```

You could also create a type for the outer array:

```
// A list of matrices
type MatrixSet = Matrix[];

const exampleC: MatrixSet = [];
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghsATgSwB4CUD2B3KBeKAbQDsBXAWwCMJEAaKMqm%20x6xAXQG4AoUSWBClT4i8JGizZ6YoZOmCJOLr3DQZaAMoRgI9akLLuAY0zEAzjoio45MABsIALgHj97EYW5RvRLz-%20EAAy0wYHstH7%203oQAjLRxMeGRUUEhIUn%204b5RPqlxYRE50cH5GUV56YU%207Nw1xqYWUFY29hAAKtiYznoGHoYm5pbWtg5tABaIEE4uQlo6BAacQA)

Comment: I think this achieves what they are asking for.  It makes it easier to read the type name and know what sort of data structure you are dealing with, without having to count brackets or think about it too much.